# Excel Visual Basic Strange Automation Error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that ran fine for years until today. I'm now getting this error:

Run-time error '-2147319767 (80028029)
Automation error
Invalid forward reference, or reference to uncompiled type.

The error happens in the first line of code:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    If Left(ActiveSheet.Name, 4) = "Plan" And Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
        i = ActiveSheet.Index
        If i = 1 Then
            Sheets(2).Activate
        Else
            Sheets(1).Activate
        End If
        Sheets(i).Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is with "ActiveSheet.name". Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. Maybe there is a [missing reference](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/missingreferences.aspx) which causes this behaviour

Comment: You might benefit from reading [this short Auto_Open article](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/events/auto-open.htm). Have you tried qualifying the worksheets (sheets) with `ThisWorkbook` e.g. `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet...`?